# why i am said my indentation code is not correct?

Tags: function, visual-studio-code, lisp, common-lisp, indentation

I have to indent properly this code (common lisp):

Code 1

```
(defun supérieurs (nombre liste)
   (cond
      ((not liste) 0)
      ((>= (car liste) nombre) (+ 1 (supérieurs nombre (cdr liste))))
      ((supérieurs nombre (cdr liste))) ) )
```

Code 2

```
(defun supérieurs (nombre liste)
  (cond
      ((not liste) nil)
      ((>= (car liste) nombre) 
          (cons (car liste) (supérieurs nombre (cdr liste))) )
      ((supérieurs nombre (cdr liste))) ) )
```

Code 3

```
(defun nombres (liste)
   (cond
      ((not liste) 0)
      ((and (listp (car liste)) (numberp (car (car liste))))
            (+ 1 (nombres (cdr liste))) )   
      ((nombres (cdr liste))) ) )
```

Code 4

```
(defun nombre (liste)
  (cond
    ((not liste) nil)
    ((and (listp (car liste)) (numberp (car (car liste))))
        (cons (car liste) (nombre (cdr liste))) )   
    ((nombre (cdr liste))) ) )
```

Code 5

```
(defun begin (lettre liste)
  (cond
    ((atom liste) 0)
    ((and 
        (not (equal (car liste) nil)) 
        (equal (char (string (car liste)) 0) (char (string lettre) 0)))
        (+ 1 (begin lettre (cdr liste))) )
    ((begin lettre (cdr liste))) ) )
```

I don't understand why it's not.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: https://google.github.io/styleguide/lispguide.xml

Comment: Not 100% related to indentation but the ending parenthesis is hurting my feelings `))) ) )`. The idiomatic way to write this down is `)))))`. With a proper editor, the parenthesis font color is gray so that the parenthesis can be mostly ignored. The indentation is very important for reading sexp-based code, so it's better to keep it standard. It's also helping a lot to detect wrong parenthesis.

Comment: You have three different indentations for clauses in your `cond`s (2, 3 and 4 spaces) and two different indentations for function bodies after `defun`.  At most one of each of them can be correct (and in fact *none* of the indentations for `cond` is correct!).  Also just don't do the awful `) ) ))) ))` thing: that's awful.  If you're writing Python do you carefully leave spaces at the end of blocks (or, worse, carefully leave the right number of blank lines where the invisible close braces which aren't there go)?  No.  So don't do that in Lisp.

Comment: The purpose of indentation is to make the code readable, to be able to see the code's *structure* at a glance. More nested entities should be indented more than the outer level ones; same level -- the same. E.g. in `(and ...xpr1... ...xpr2...)`, with non-trivial subexpressions, I much prefer the second on its separate line, indented under the first. Dunno if it's standard or not. I also prefer cond case's body indented at least 2 spaces more than the test, even though the standard indentation is the same as test -- which makes it an indiscernible wall of text, for me. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Use indentation of the editor. Avoid indenting with tabs.

```
(defun nombre (liste)
  (cond
    ((not liste) nil)
    ((and (listp (car liste)) (numberp (car (car liste))))
        (cons (car liste) (nombre (cdr liste))) )     
     ;  ^
     ;  |  Why this indentation?
    ((nombre (cdr liste))) ) )


(defun begin (lettre liste)
  (cond
    ((atom liste) 0)
    ((and 
        (not (equal (car liste) nil)) 
        (equal (char (string (car liste)) 0) (char (string lettre) 0)))
        (+ 1 (begin lettre (cdr liste))) )
     ;  ^
     ;  |  Why this indentation?
    ((begin lettre (cdr liste))) ) )


(defun nombres (liste)
   (cond
      ((not liste) 0)
      ((and (listp (car liste)) (numberp (car (car liste))))
            (+ 1 (nombres (cdr liste))) )
         ;  ^
         ;  |  Why this indentation?
   
      ((nombres (cdr liste))) ) )
```

Comment: that's the problem with the pretty print in lisp ...you must add a space when you close a parenthesis not on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of indentation is to make the code readable, to be able to see the code's *structure* at a glance. More nested entities should be indented more than the outer level ones; same level -- the same. E.g. in `(and ...xpr1... ...xpr2...)`, with non-trivial subexpressions, I much prefer the second on its separate line, indented under the first, as

```
    (and ...xpr1... 
         ...xpr2...)
```

Don't know if it's standard or not. I also prefer `cond` case's body indented at  2 spaces more than the test, even though the standard indentation is the same as the test -- which makes it an indiscernible wall of text, for me. YMMV.

Following these principles, I'd format your code snippets the following way (although as I mentioned, the `cond` formatting is non-standard and is bound to draw the ire of some).

Code 1

```
(defun supérieurs (nombre liste)
  (cond
    ((not liste) 0)
    ((>= (car liste) nombre)
       (+ 1 (supérieurs nombre (cdr liste))))
    ((supérieurs nombre (cdr liste)))))
```

Code 2

```
(defun supérieurs (nombre liste)
  (cond
    ((not liste) nil)
    ((>= (car liste) nombre) 
       (cons (car liste) 
             (supérieurs nombre (cdr liste))))
    ((supérieurs nombre (cdr liste)))))
```

Code 3

```
(defun nombres (liste)
  (cond
    ((not liste) 0)
    ((and (listp (car liste)) 
          (numberp (car (car liste))))
       (+ 1 (nombres (cdr liste))) )   
    ((nombres (cdr liste)))))
```

Code 4

```
(defun nombre (liste)
  (cond
    ((not liste) nil)
    ((and (listp (car liste))
          (numberp (car (car liste))))
       (cons (car liste) (nombre (cdr liste))))   
    ((nombre (cdr liste)))))
```

Code 5

```
(defun begin (lettre liste)
  (cond
    ((atom liste) 0)
    ((and (not (equal (car liste) nil)) 
          (equal (char (string (car liste)) 0)
                 (char (string lettre) 0)))
       (+ 1 (begin lettre (cdr liste))))
    ((begin lettre (cdr liste)))))
```